# Trying to parse tag element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to parse a web page with JavaScript targeting list `<li>` without class.

```
<ul id="cartItems">
  <li class="heading">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My aim is to get the  list without list class in the format <li>...</li> <li>...</li> <li>...</li> <li>...</li>

Comment: Do you really need to _parse_ the HTML or do you just need to get the elements? What is your expected end result?

Comment: i want to get the list tag without class

Comment: Thanks @Marwelln   it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all `li` elements without a class.

```js
var liWithoutClass = document.querySelectorAll('#cartItems > li:not([class])');

console.log(liWithoutClass);

document.write(liWithoutClass[0].textContent); // Output the first li
document.write('<br />' + liWithoutClass[3].textContent); // Output the last li
```

```html
<ul id="cartItems">
  <li class="heading">Heading</li>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var elems = document.querySelector(".heading");
    console.log(elems);
//Now we strip the class out like this:
    elems.setAttribute(class, "none");
//Now we display the updated values below
console.log(elems);  
// This won't work in Stack's editor, so you'll have to validate it against the page you want.
//Now, just grab the entire element by id from the page as below:

var updatedContent = document.getElementById("cartItems");
console.log(updatedContent);
//Again, stack's editor is limited, but overall this should work fine on your page.
```

```html
    <ul id="cartItems">
      <li class="heading">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
```